Flutter with JavaScript
To all my fellow JavaScript experts I need your help. In my Flutter app, I used JavaScript, can anyone help me edit my JavaScript code? I can get the URL and print for every click, but I don't need the video to be played. Your help is highly appreciated.
Behavior needed for my Flutter app:

I need to get the link each time I select video from https://www.youtube.com/ but I don't need the video to be played.
void initializeJavaScript() {
 webViewController.runJavaScript('''
   (function() {
     function sendMessage(url) {
       Toaster.postMessage(url);
     }

     var videos = document.getElementsByTagName('video');
         var audios = document.getElementsByTagName('audio');
         for (var i = 0; i < videos.length; i++) {
           videos[i].muted = true;
         }
         for (var i = 0; i < audios.length; i++) {
           audios[i].muted = true;
         }

     var lastUrl = location.href;
     new MutationObserver(() => {
       var url = location.href;
       if (url !== lastUrl) {
         lastUrl = url;
         if (url.includes('/watch')) {
           sendMessage(url);
         }
       }
     }).observe(document, {subtree: true, childList: true});
   })();
 ''');}



